# For harmonic function $U$, prove that $\int_{C_r}\partial_xUdy-\partial_yUdx$ is constant.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to prove that for a function $U$ harmonic in the punctured disk $0<r<r_0$, $\int_{C_r}\partial_xUdy-\partial_yUdx$, where $C_r$ is a circle of radius $r$, is a constant independent of $r$.

I know I need to use $\partial_{xx}U+\partial_{yy}U=0$ and manipulate the variables but I cannot figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: sorry, tried to delete my first comment after I realised that it was silly.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_theorem does it, I think.

Comment: @Hayeder How would I use this theorem? Can I say that this integral is equal to $\partial_{xx}U+\partial_{yy}U=0$ directly? The answer shows that when $U$ is not bounded, the result is not zero.

Comment: Maybe there is a technicality that I do not know about, then. But it looks to me like the integrand will be $0$ when using Green's Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U_x dy - U_ydx = \nabla U \cdot \mathbf{n} ds$

Since $d\mathbf{r} = (dx,dy)$, thus $d\mathbf{n} = (dy,-dx)$, which is orthogonal to $d\mathbf{r}$.

And $d\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{n}ds$.

$\int \nabla U \cdot \mathbf{n}ds = \int \nabla^2 Ud\sigma = (\int_{r<\epsilon}+\int_{r\ge\epsilon}) \nabla^2 Ud\sigma$.

Comment: Thank you, but can you give some more detail because Im not so familiar with the formula and theorems.

Comment: @ShuXiaoLi simply use Green's formula to that.

Comment: But the answer turns out to be nonzero when $U$ is not bounded in the disk. So I dont know where is the problem

Comment: because your $U$ has singularity in the disk... like $\ln(x^2+y^2)$. It will be zero if $u$ is harmonic throughout the disk. @ShuXiaoLi

Comment: Sorry, I still dont get it. If U has a singularity, then Green's Theorem will not work, right? So what can we do now?

Comment: it works, all you need is the integral doesn't depend on $r$. singularity only happens at $(0,0)$, so you just choose two circle and compare the values of integrals.

Comment: Right! Thank you so much. I thought we could explicitly find out the result, which is a constant